# Counting how many times an async button has been pressed (or if some operation is going on)

Tags: c#, async-await

I know that for async operations it is possible to track its progress, but I will try that later. Now I have a simple window forms apply with a button (or a pair of buttons - the number does not matter). The buttons call an async operation

```
public async void Button1_Click(...)
{
   await Button1_OperationAsync(...);
}
```

If I don't press the button nothing is going on but if I press it once the `Button1_OperationAsync` starts (and is awaited). (I am not really sure if to call it "a thread").

But what happens if I press the button *twice*? Well then before the first async operation finishes, the `Button1_OperationAsync` is called again. (Or if another similar button is pressed then a `Button2_OperationAsync` is called)

Maybe even the second async operation would finish *before* the first one.

What I want is a simple way of knowing if any operation is going on. So what I thought is to have a variable and increment it when an operation is called and decrement it when an operation is finished. Something like

```
int numberOfOps=0;
public async void Button1_Click(...)
{  numberOfOps++;
   textBox1.Text="Started!";
   await Button1_OpeationAsync(...);
   numberOfOps--;
   if(numberOfOps<=0) 
     {
      textBox1.Text="Done!";
     }
}
```

Be aware that this code would go in the other button (Button2) too. Or many other buttons.

I am aware that issues of synchronization might be involved. So I would appreciate advice on what I am trying to do in order to do correctly

Answer (score 1):

When using `async`/`await` you're not using any threads for the UI code other than the UI-thread. It's possible that the code that gets called in the `Button1_OpeationAsync` method might use a separate thread, but the calling code will remain on the UI thread.

Try having a play with this code:

```
private int numberOfOps = 0;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = $"Started! {++numberOfOps}";
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0));
    textBox1.Text = $"Started! {--numberOfOps}";
    if (numberOfOps == 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Done!";
    }
}
```

It works just fine. You can use the `numberOfOps` variable across multiple buttons.

If you'd like to make it easy to re-use the code, try it this way:

```
    int numberOfOps = 0;

    private async Task RunOp(Func<Task> op)
    {
        textBox1.Text = $"Started! {++numberOfOps}";
        await op();
        textBox1.Text = $"Started! {--numberOfOps}";
        if (numberOfOps == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.RunOp(() => Button1_OpeationAsync(...));
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.RunOp(() => Button2_OpeationAsync(...));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a task array, and a task object at class level:

```
private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
private Task task = null;
```

In each of your click handlers do something like this:

```
var operationTask = SomeOperationAsync(...);
tasks.Add(operationTask);
task = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

if (task.IsCompleted)
{
    // no operation is going on
    tasks.Clear();

    // do what ever you want to do further
}
else
{
     //some operation is going on
}
```